# SQL query returning fieldnames but not values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I am trying to return the Field values.  I tried it in PHP and it works but returns the same field over and over.  So tested by doing a direct query and this is what I get...

Here is the function that I use to grab the data:

```
<?php

function display_orders( $user_id, $limit ) {

    $data = array();

    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $limit = (int)$limit;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    //print_r($func_get_args);

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {

        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        unset($func_get_args[1]);


        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';

            for($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {    

                $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT $fields
                                                          FROM  `users` ,  `vendor` 
                                                          WHERE $user_id = users.id 
                                                          AND $user_id = vendor.user_id 
                                                          ORDER BY vendor.DateRequested DESC") );

            }

        return $data;
    }

}

?>
```

This will return the following and it will just loop the newegg entry over and over.

[image]

Thanks for all your help I love this community!

Comment: I like that you use `var_dump()`, please note that you can use also `<pre>print_r($var)</pre>` it is easier to read.

Comment: Do not quote the column names in your query.

Comment: I been learning from youtube videos...  is print_r better to use over echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT 'field'` (single quotes, as in your phpmyadmin query) selects the literal *string* `field`.

`` SELECT `field` `` (backticks, as in your PHP query) selects the *values* from the field named `field`.

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns a *single row* from a query result handle.  You are meant to capture the return of `mysql_query()`, which is a result handle, and repeatedly "fetch" rows from that.  Instead you call `mysql_query()` a number of times, returning a new result set each time, and fetch the first row from the result set each time.

***UPDATE***

You want something like this:

```
$results = mysql_query(...);
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
  $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
}
```

It would perhaps be a better idea to put that `$limit` inside the query itself (LIMIT ...).

Comment: So  I need to loop the query and return the next value in the array?  That makes sense!  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Wait just checked and it is looped...  Am I missing something there?

Comment: @HELPMEPLEASE, the [docs for `mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) show how it is supposed to be used.  You are calling `mysql_query()` in a loop — the `mysql_fetch_assoc` is merely incidental the way you are doing it.

Comment: Hmm Ill go over the docs but is there a different function im supposed to use to fetch the data.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @HELPMEPLEASE, updated answer.  If any of this proves helpful, don't hesitate to upvote and/or accept.

Comment: Thanks for giving the complete answer!  You are awesome and super helpful

Comment: @HELPMEPLEASE, you're welcome. ☺ I'd be remiss if, now that you've got a handle on things, I didn't point out that you really should be using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you quote the column names which means for every matching row from the result of your query, that value will be returned as a column.

Simply remove the quotes around your columns. Try it for one column first, verify it works and then do the same for the rest.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the query in phpmyadmin... The looping issue is still present.

Comment: The looping issue is most likely due to the query. Print the query that the PHP script runs, run that through phpMyAdmin and see the results. See pilcrows answer below also.